SwiftUI Animation in Tabbar
I am wanting to animate switching between tabs but the animation are very hard. I tried using matched geometry but the animation was wacky. Could be lack of understanding on matched geometry.
The expectation:
Tapping on a tab will show the image icon and the title of the tab behind a capsule.
The untapped tab will not show the title or have the capsule behind it. Once a new tab is selected the capsule will navigate to the selected tab. and the title of the previously selected tab will hide.
import SwiftUI

struct Tabbar: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @State var selectedTab: RootTab = .home
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(RootTab.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                    TabButton(tab: tab)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.4))
            .cornerRadius(30, corners: .allCorners)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
    }
    
    private func TabButton(tab: RootTab) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: tab.systemName)
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .bold()
            
            if selectedTab == tab {
                Text(tab.title)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .animation(.default, value: selectedTab)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                selectedTab = tab
            }
        }
        .if(selectedTab == tab) { view in
            view
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .background { Color.blue }
                .cornerRadius(15, corners: .allCorners)
                .animation(.default, value: selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

enum RootTab: String, CaseIterable {
    case home
    case profile
    
    var systemName: String {
        switch self {
            case .home: return "house"
            case .profile: return "person.crop.circle"
        }
    }
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
            case .home: return "Home"
            case .profile: return "Profile"
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, transform: (Self) -> some View) -> some View {
        if condition() {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape(RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}



As you were suggesting, .matchedGeometryEffect can be used to achieve this animation:

The moving background should be shown as background to the HStack, before applying padding and a colored background. This way, it does not impact the size of the ZStack. In fact, the ZStack is not actually needed.

The position and size of the moving background is matched to the selected tab button using .matchedGeometryEffect with isSource: false. The id of the selected tab is used as the id to match to.

Since the size of the background marker is determined by the selected button, the padding should be applied to the buttons themselves.

The view extension .if is not needed.


Other suggested changes:

The tab buttons are performing the change using withAnimation, so there is no need for any .animation modifiers.

The modifier .cornerRadius is deprecated, use .clipShape instead. An easy way to get a shape with fully rounded ends is to use a Capsule.

The modifier .foregroundColor is also deprecated, use .foregroundStyle instead.

If you want to apply the system background as background color, there is no need to create a Color from a UIColor, just use ShapeStyle.background instead.


struct Tabbar: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @State var selectedTab: RootTab = .home

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(RootTab.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                TabButton(tab: tab)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: tab, in: animation)
            }
        }
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.blue)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedTab, in: animation, isSource: false)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
        .background(.blue.opacity(0.4))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.background)
    }

    private func TabButton(tab: RootTab) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: tab.systemName)
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .bold()

            if selectedTab == tab {
                Text(tab.title)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                selectedTab = tab
            }
        }
    }
}


You will notice that the width of the tab bar changes a little when the selection changes, because the two labels have different widths. This also causes the left-most icon to move a little.
To prevent this, the footprint for the largest label can be found by using a hidden ZStack that contains all of the labels shown on top of each other. The visible label can then be shown as an overlay over the footprint:
// function TabButton

if selectedTab == tab {
    ZStack {
        ForEach(RootTab.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
            Text(tab.title)
        }
    }
    .hidden()
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(tab.title)
    }
    .font(.callout)
    .bold()
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
}


If in fact you know which label is always the longest (in all languages) then you don't need the ZStack, you could just use a hidden version of this wide label instead.

Perfect! Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. The explanation of the matched geometry makes sense. I see where i went wrong.
